# \cleardoublepage without showing and incrementing page number

Tags: emptypage

I have a question regarding `\cleardoublepage`.
I want to emulate the package `emptypage` but with the modification that the page number shouldn't increment by 1.

An example:

titlepage (p. 1) -> \cleardoublepage -> second page (p. 2)

I tried modifying the `emptypage` package and adding `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` when creating a new page. The issue I am facing is that the check if the page is odd is using this exact counter. I am searching for a way to get the absolute page number as an integer or for another solution to my problem.

This is the .sty I currently have (adapted from `emptypackage`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{uncountingemptypage}

\def\uncountingemptypage@emptypage{
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \addtocounter{page}{-1} % <-- page counter modification
    \if@twocolumn
        \hbox{}
        \newpage
    \fi
}
\def\cleardoublepage{
    \clearpage
    \if@twoside
        \ifodd \c@page % <-- odd-check
        \else
            \uncountingemptypage@emptypage
        \fi
    \fi
}
```

I also tried using `zref` for the absolute page number, but I failed in implementing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to confuse your readers by not counting a page and by making an even page to a right page?

Comment: I want to start new chapters on a completely new piece of paper.

Comment: But a new piece of paper should either have page number 1 or 3 but not 2.

Comment: I have never seen any book where the  page numbering does not count the blank pages that are used to make the chapters start on the right hand page. Are you sure you want to do this?